# When using CMD-Tab, how to re-open the app's main window?

Tags: keyboard, windows, dock, window-manager, application-switcher

I hit this problem often when interacting with some Apple applications, mainly **Messages** and **iTunes**.

After starting a song with iTunes, to clear my screen and get back to work I close the iTunes *window* with <kbd>CMD-W</kbd>. The iTunes *application* is still running in my Dock and playing music.

After some time, I want to switch to a different album. I <kbd>CMD-Tab</kbd> to select the iTunes application. iTunes is focused in the menu bar. But **no window is shown**, because I previously closed the window.

This workflow occurs for all apps, and is not usually a problem. If I switch to Safari and no window is open, I simply press <kbd>CMD-T</kbd> or <kbd>CMD-N</kbd> to open a new tab or new window.

With iTunes, I press <kbd>CMD-N</kbd> and nothing happens. No iTunes window is created or shown. The Application is focused, but the main window is not re-opened if it is currently closed.

I end up clicking on the Dock, which (in addition to focusing the application) opens a new iTunes *window* if that window was previously closed.

This breaks my (usually more efficient) <kbd>CMD-Tab</kbd> workflow. If I'm forced to click the iTunes dock icon, I may as well just click the dock icon from the start and forgo the keyboard shortcut.

Messages has a similar problem. If I receive a desktop notification and use <kbd>CMD-Tab</kbd> to open Messages to respond, the application will be focused but no window will be opened. I can press <kbd>CMD-N</kbd>, which in Message's case *does* open a new window, but the "new message" cell will be opened rather than the existing conversation I had open and now want to respond to.

When clicking the Dock icon or opening the app via a Spotlight Search, if the main window is not open then it will be re-opened. Is there a way to force this behavior for <kbd>CMD-Tab</kbd> app selection?

How do I show the main window when the Application is focused via <kbd>CMD-Tab</kbd>?

Comment: [Hold Down the Option Key When Switching Between Apps on Mac To Pull Up a Minimized App](http://lifehacker.com/hold-down-the-option-key-when-switching-between-apps-on-1785805539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several applications including iTunes let you switch views by using `CMD` +`<number>`.  `CMD` + `0` will give you the main window. But some applications like iTunes offer different views.

Just try `CMD`+`tab` to iTunes and then variate between `CMD` + `1` to `9` to see which view you like. In the screenshot below you can see the different options for iTunes. Messages only has the option `CMD` + `0`.

[image]

Comment: This is great! I was looking for a "Open Window"-type command that I could remap but was unable to find anything. In Messages it's `Window > Messages`. I'm going to remap that to CMD-1 and use that keyboard shortcut as "re-open the window" for all apps where I have this problem. It seems like many apps will have this command by default.

Answer (score 5):

There exists a shortcut for that, though it requires certain dexterity:

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the app, but then, before releasing <kbd>Command</kbd>, hold <kbd>Option</kbd>.

If you then release <kbd>Command</kbd> while still holding <kbd>Option</kbd>, the window should pop open.

It's just like clicking in the app icon in the Dock (if there are no windows open, one opens; if there is a minimized window, it appears again).

Comment: Thank you, that definitely does work. Unfortunately it seems to require 2 thumbs! Additional answers that set a preference or remap that key would be appreciated, if anyone knows.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!