# Workaround for command + tab issue on Messages, Notes, etc

Tags: keybindings, bettertouchtool

I'm having [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264859/when-using-cmd-tab-how-to-re-open-the-apps-main-window) issue where certain apps (Messages, Notes) aren't brought to the screen when I `command + tab` over to them. One solution is to press `option` at the same time, as said in the link. But that's a pretty cumbersome keypress.

Has anyone found a clean workaround for this, using Better Touch Tool, for instance? If I just mapped `command + tab` to `command + option + tab`, would it work? Would it distort the normal `command + tab` behavior for other apps?

What is the point of this weird OS behavior, anyway?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Messages - just with Notes. When I close the Messages window, switch away, then Command+Tab back, the window re-appears.

Comment: This behavior isn't weird, per se. You have simply made an application without any windows active. One would ask whether, if you have no documents open in Text Edit, you would expect your most recent document to be summoned if you performed the same operation.

Comment: @Ezekiel I understand what you mean. I guess what I'm saying is what is the point of having <click on dock icon> have different behavior from <command + tab to app>?

Comment: Fair point, no answer there. I see it as a slightly less intentional action, command-tabbing, so fewer side effects (such as creating a new window). But I agree that window management needs some streamlining.